# Pandas - Break nested json into multiple rows

Tags: pandas

I have my Dataframe in the below structure. I would like to break them based on the nested values within the details column

```
cust_id, name, details
101, Kevin, [{"id":1001,"country":"US","state":"OH"}, {"id":1002,"country":"US","state":"GA"}]
102, Scott, [{"id":2001,"country":"US","state":"OH"}, {"id":2002,"country":"US","state":"GA"}]
```

Expected output

```
cust_id, name, id, country, state
101, Kevin, 1001, US, OH
101, Kevin, 1002, US, GA
102, Scott, 2001, US, OH
102, Scott, 2002, US, GA
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```py
df = df.explode('details').reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.merge(pd.json_normalize(df['details']), left_index=True, right_index=True).drop('details', axis=1)
```

1. `df.explode("details")` basically duplicates each row in the `details` N times, where N is the number of items in the array (if any) of `details` of that row
2. Since `explode` duplicates the rows, the original rows' indices (0 and 1) are copied to the new rows, so their indices are 0, 0, 1, 1, which messes up later processing. `reset_index()` creates a fresh new column for the index, starting at `0`. `drop=True` is used because by default pandas will keep the old index column; this removes it.
3. `pd.json_normalize(df['details'])` converts the column (where each row contains a JSON object) to a new dataframe where each key unique of all the JSON objects is new column
4. `df.merge()` merges the new dataframe into the original one
5. `left_index=True` and `right_index=True` tells pandas to merge the specified dataframe starting from it's first, row into this dataframe, starting at *its* first row
6. `.drop('details', axis=1)` gets rid of the old `details` column containing the old objects

Comment: thanks for responding. I am however getting an error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'` when I execute the second line

Comment: Oh weird. The dataframe you're running this on must not have the same structure as the sample one in your question. What does it look like?

Comment: though the number of columns might differ the structure is exactly the same. I am seeing the explode method (step 1) does not change the Dataframe. I also did check the pandas version and it is 1.0.5

Comment: Hmm, that's pretty old. Will you please try with the latest version, 1.3.4?

Comment: It could be that your dictionary list is read as string. Try adding `df["details"] = df["details"].apply(ast.literal_eval)` at the beginning

Comment: You're probably right; good catch @Tranbi!!

Comment: @Tranbi thanks for jumping in.. I did try your suggestion but got the below error

`ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x7ffe4207ec10>`

Comment: @kevin get it working yet?

Comment: @user17242583 still having the same issue

Comment: Will you please show a little bit of the result of `print(df.to_dict())` in your question?

Comment: @user17242583 I was able to get this working by doing the below

`df["details"] = df["details"].apply(json.loads)`

Appreciate all the help from your end.. Thanks

Comment: Great! I'm sorry it was so hard :(

Comment: @user17242583 no worries appreciate all your help